# initilizing a struct with input parameter

Tags: c++, boost, struct, initialization, c++11

i am newbie at c++ and i have problem initializing my container *`occ_stat_t`* using the member function *`CNetwork::CNetwork`*.

i guess that something is wrong at line: *`occ_stat[0]( num_elements_ ) , occ_stat[1]( num_elements_ )`* but i dont really know how to write it correctly.

i would like to learn how to initialize my struct, that in each *`occ_stat`*,  *`occupied_counter`* will contains *`n`* elements and *`mean_life_time`* will be assign the value `0`.

i would appreciate any help.

regards

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <cstdint>

typedef boost::multi_array< uint32_t , 1> uint32_1d_t;

struct occ_stat_t {
    occ_stat_t (uint32_t n ):
            occupied_counter( boost::extents[n] ) {}

    uint32_1d_t occupied_counter;
    double      mean_life_time;
};

class CNetwork {
public:
    CNetwork ( uint32_t num_elements_ );

private:
    occ_stat_t  occ_stat[2];

};

CNetwork::CNetwork ( uint32_t num_elements_ ) 
: occ_stat[0]( num_elements_ ) , occ_stat[1]( num_elements_ )
{
    // do something
}

int main( ) {

    uint8_t foo = 5;
    CNetwork Network(foo);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: i am using gnu++0x standard (dont know what is the difference to c++0x)

Comment: would it be better to redefine the struct as a class? (with initialization method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to access array subscripts in initializer lists. Unless on C++0x - which you are - but not in VS 2010 since it is not implemented there.

So you've got to:

```
CNetwork::CNetwork ( uint32_t num_elements_ ) 
{
    occ_stat[0].occupied_counter =  boost::extents[num_elements_];
    occ_stat[1].occupied_counter =  boost::extents[num_elements_];

    //or 

    occ_stat[0] = occ_stat_t(num_elements_);
    occ_stat[1] = occ_stat_t(num_elements_);

    // do something
}
```

EDIT:

Ok so you also have to add an default-constructor since we are initializing it in the initializer list, so:

```
struct occ_stat_t {

    occ_stat_t () : occupied_countr(/*default_to_whatever_boost_extents is*/){};

    /* Don't need this one we default construct now
    occ_stat_t (uint32_t n ):
            occupied_counter( boost::extents[n] ) {}
    */

    uint32_1d_t occupied_counter;
    double      mean_life_time;
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but doesn't work... maybe something in your answer is missing, since you left at the second line ":"

Comment: @Eagle Glad it worked. I just compiled it with VS2010 and boost 1.44 and it worked. I got a bunch of warnings but no errors. If this answer solved your problem mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Eagle i was wondering why you need boost::multi_array if you are only storing a 1D array. Wouldn't std::vector<uint32_t> also be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Elements in a primitive array are constructed *only* with their default constructor. So you can't initialize such a data member like that.

However, why do you need that array[2] data member occ_stat?
Won't it be better to have 2 members with more specific names?

```
class CNetwork {
public:
    CNetwork ( uint32_t num_elements_ );

private:
    occ_stat_t  occ_stat_for_somthing;
    occ_stat_t  occ_stat_for_another;

};

CNetwork::CNetwork ( uint32_t num_elements_ ) 
:
  occ_stat_for_something( num_elements_ ) , 
  occ_stat_for_another( num_elements_ )
{
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. You are write that it will solve my problem (i apply it yesterday), but in over function members (that are not part of this example) it is simpler to use for-loop instead of writing the code double. Probably there is also another way to imply it, but since i am newbie, i find it easier as an array... thanks again